# Finding out the total math played

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Do i need to guess  the number of games in the first half the .6  of the numbers of games? Tips please how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the total number of games played last season, $w$ the total number of wins in the first half of last season. Since the team played $20$ games in the second half of the year, then the first condition can be rewritten as $$0.60=\frac{w}{n-20}.$$ Can you see why? Can you rephrase the last condition into an equation, too, using the fact that the team won $3$ games in the second half of the season?

Comment: first equation for , total win divided by number of games?

Comment: Yes, that's what we want for our other equation.

Comment: Okay I have got it now. Where is gone $.5= \frac{w+3}{n}$ in your answer?

Comment: I removed it (clearly too late for you to have not seen it), because I didn't want to give you *too* much information at the outset, and deriving one equation suggested how to derive the second.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, I'm assuming each game is either a win or a loss; if there are draws, lump them in with the losses.

Since the team lost $14$ more games than they won in the second half, in order to end up at $50\%$ they must have won $14$ more than they lost in the first half. Those $14$ games are $60\% - 40\% = 20\%$ of the games they played in the first half.  So how may games did they play in the first half?